# Link facebook page posts images to website

Tags: facebook

I have facebook page from my websites, http://www.facebook.com/scrapehere

I have posts on daily basis. Is there anyway where I an link post images to websites?
i.e., If users click images, I should be able to take them directly to website(scrapehere.com).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible for you to decide what happen when someone clicks on the photo.